# cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text - Pq usar?

Tags: c#, sql

Galera bom dia.

Estou populando um grid, e apos pesquisar na internet, vi que alguns utilização o comando:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

Minha duvida, é, pq utilizar? qual a diferença? fiz alguns testes aqui, e funciona normalmente com ou sem esse parâmetro.

Segue meu código:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sqlstring, _sql;
        int id_cliente = 3;

        sqlstring = @"Server=tcp:tpspoazsql01.database.windows.net,1433;Data Source=tpspoazsql01.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=Onee;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=********;Password=*********;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;";
        _sql = string.Empty;

        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(sqlstring);

        try
        {
            _sql = @"SELECT nome,endereco,numero,bairro,cidade,estado,cep FROM Cliente_enderecos_alter WHERE id_cliente = @id_cliente AND tipo = 'Cobrança'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(_sql, sqlconn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id_cliente", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id_cliente;

            sqlconn.Open();

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable clientes = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(clientes);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = clientes;
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acontece que o padrão da propriedade `CommandType` é o **`CommandType.Text`**. Por isso funciona mesmo sem você explicitá-lo.

Isso não quer dizer que seu comando vá funcionar sem isso, sempre será necessário ter algum valor nesta propriedade. Os valores possíveis são :

1. **`StoredProcedure`** - Executa uma procedure. O comando vai ser o nome + parâmetros desta procedure;
2. **`TableDirect`** - Retorna informações sobre uma tabela. O comando deve ser o nome da tabela;
3. **`Text`** - O comando deve ser um SQL.

Veja na screenshot que no momento que o objeto é criado o `CommandType` já é **`CommandType.Text`**.

[image: Criação do objeto]

Comment: Amigo bom dia. Entendi. Obrigado pela explicação.

Comment: Sempre um prazer ajudar, jovem.

Answer (score 2):

Não é necessário usar neste seu caso. No seu exemplo o `CommandType` não faz diferença nenhuma, isso porque o valor padrão de um enum de `CommandType` é o valor `CommandType.Text`.

`CommandType` pode ser modificado quando você quer chamar uma `Procedure` com o uso do `Parameters` do `SqlCommand`, para garantir assim algumas validações como `SQL Injection`. (`CommandType.StoredProcedure` para isso)

Também tem outra opção de `TableDirect`, mas nunca usei e não conheço direito, então só estou comentando sobre ele para caso queira pesquisar.

[Aqui no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542517/call-a-stored-procedure-with-parameter-in-c-sharp) tem uma pergunta que mostra como se usar o `StoredProcedure` com `Parameters`.

Comment: Amigo bom dia. Perfeito, entendi, obrigado pela explicação vou ver o link que vc mandou. valeu